# Error when running a SOAP request through Jmeter - Response 500

Tags: jmeter

i'm trying to setup a SOAP webservice load test however when I run it I get the below:

Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 614
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 14 Apr 2016 11:45:48 GMT

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8

Please see screen shot of how it has been setup ...note that:

Webservice = https://testws.thedx.co.uk/R2UAT/Router/ProcessOrder_v2_0/ProcessOrder.svc

Webserver =https://webservices.dxdelivery.com/ProcessOrder/Router/

HTTP Request Default[image: HTTP Request Default]

HTTP Authorization Manager[image: HTTP Authorization Manager]

Soap Request[image: Soap Request]

HTTP Header Manager[image: HTTP Header Manager]

View Results Tree[image: View Result Tree]

can anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked at Server Logs?  Can you replicate using the SOAP request using another tool to show that is JMeter vs something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What you provide in HTTP Request Sampler overrides what you configure in HTTP Request Defaults.
2. What you provide in "Path" overrides what you configure in "Server Name or IP". So basically you're hitting `https://testws.thedx.co.uk/R2UAT/Router/ProcessOrder_v2_0/ProcessOrder.svc` URL.
3. HTTP Authorization Manager doesn't seem to work (I don't see `Authorization: Basic .....` header)
4. Most likely you're missing [SOAPAction header](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html) as well

It's hard to say anything certain without seeing request, response and server log, hopefully above hints will be useful. Other things you can try are:

- Try sending the same request using [SoapUI](http://soapui.org/) tool, if request succeeds - replicate it in JMeter. By the way, SoapUI has some [load testing capabilities](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/load-testing.html) as well (quite limited though)
- Check out [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more useful hints.

Answer (score 0):

You will have too look in the server logs .
But if you have Basic Auth, switch implementation in Http Request to Httpclient3.1